# how to setup one to one relation and many to many relation in sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, associations, relationship

i have a model of three table user,product,cart. now i want that one cart row belong to one user only. but a cart row can have many product . sequelize doc does not have much details of setter and getter or i am confused. below is my code which can create user but cart is not being created at same time and without cart i can't put product in it.

```
// this is my assosiation
let db = {};


db.user = require("./user");
db.cart = require("./cart");
db.product = require("./product")


db.user.hasOne(db.cart);
db.cart.belongsTo(db.user);
db.product.belongsToMany(db.cart,{
    through:"product_cart",
    foreignKey : "productId",
    otherKey: "cartId"
});
db.cart.belongsToMany(db.product,{
    through:"product_cart",
    foreignKey:"cartId",
    otherKey:"productId"
})
```

```
// this is my user controller

let user = db.user;

let addUser = async function (req,res,next){
 let {name,email,password} = req.body;
 if(!name) return res.status(404).send("name is required")
 if(!email) return res.status(404).send("email is required")
 if(!password) return res.status(404).send("password is required")
    await user.create({
        name:name,
        email:email,
        password:password
    })

    res.status(200).send("user added");
    res.end();
}
```

```
// it is my cart controller

let addPorductIncart = async (req,res,next)=>{
    let user = await db.user.findByPk(req.params.userId)
    if(!user) return res.status(404).send("no user found");
    
    let product = await db.product.findByPk(req.body.id)

    if(!product) return res.status(404).send("no product found");

    let cart = await db.cart.findOne({
        where:{
            userId:req.params.userId
        }
    })
    if(!cart) await user.setCart(cart)
    cart = await db.cart.findOne({
        where:{
            userId:req.params.userId
        }
    })
    await cart.setProduct(product);
    let totalCost = cart.totalPrice;
    totalCost += product.price;
    await db.cart.update({totalPrice:totalCost},
        {
            where:{
                userId:userId
            }
        })
        res.status(200).send("product added").end();
}
```

i tried to create association but couldn't succeeded

Answer (score 0):

To create relation like one to one following two code work

Like you have user and cart and one cart belong to one user only

```
User.hasOne(Cart)
```

This tells that user has only and only one cart so a userId will be assigned to cart table automatically to keep track that which cart belong to which user.

So if you use below code

```
cart.hasOne(user)
```

That means one cart can have only one user so cartId will be assigned in user table but we already one userId column in cart why don't use that only to keep track of user and cart so we can use previously assigned `userId`

```
Cart.belongTo(User)
```

Means no new id will be generated

Way of using one to one association tables

There are some methods provided to use associated table like set and get

Lets suppose you have two table user and cart there are some user
but there is no cart row in cart table so there is no relation
between user and cart
set relationship betwwen table first

```
User.hasOne(Cart)
Uart.belongTo(User)
```

Now first you have to create cart first before assigning it to user

```
let cart =  await Cart.create() // here Cart is model of cart
```

Now first we have to select one user form users table

```
let user await Users.findOne({ where: { id: userId }})
```

set relationship between selected user and cart created

```
await user.addCart(cart) // here cart  is the cart that we created and user that we selected
```

What if there is cart already available but not assigned to any user
than first we have select that cart and apply set method

```
let cart = await Cart.findOne({ where: { id:cartId }})
await user.addCart(cart)
```

To select user cart we can user get method

```
user.getCarts();
```

To set relation between one to many we can use `belongToMany` method
suppose in a user and address table one user can have many table but one address can not have many user

```
User.hasMany(Address) // new userId column created in Address table
Address.belongTo(User) // tells that one address can be of one user only
```

If you want to assign address to user than use

```
await user.addAddress(address) // address => particular present row in Address table not whole Address table // user => paticular selected person not table
```

If you want to assign many address to a user than

```
await user.setAddresses([{},{},{}]) // object are address from the address table
```

To get address

```
await user.getAddresses();
```

There are many other method to work with them

Same little complex thing apply in many to many relation

Careful to use singular and plural things it messed up the sequelize
set and get method accept only plural thighs like `setAddresses` `setcarts` `setPeople` `getAddress` etc but add accept both singular and plural like addAddress and addAddress both have different meaning same way `addPeople`, `addPerson`

Comment: Thank you very much for correcting my mistakes. I am new here so didn't know much about it. I will try my best in improving in upcoming Q/A